# c++ - Will this cause any issues? Assigning a var using a function that passes itself as a parameter (hard for me to explain)

Tags: c++

---

So it's very hard to explain so I'll just show it to you. I'm trying to implement a Red-Black tree in C++. Below is the code relevant to the question (complete code at [this link](https://github.com/JWeinmann/Red-Black-Tree))

I'm fairly new so please forgive me if I don't use the right terminology.

My question is about creating the root node. When a new value is added using addValue, it's assigning the new node to the root but at the same time is passing the root in as the parameter. I don't get any errors but it feels like this is not a good way to go about it.

```
enum colour {RED, BLACK, DOUBLEBLACK};

struct Node{
    int data;
    int colour;
    Node *left, *right, *parent;
    explicit Node(int);
};

class Tree{

    public:
        Tree();
        virtual ~Tree(){};
        void addValue(int);
        Node* insertNode(Node *, Node*);

    private:
        Node* root;

};

Node::Node(int data) {
  this->data = data;
  colour = RED;
  left = right = parent = nullptr;
}

Tree::Tree() {
  root = nullptr;
}

void Tree::addValue(int n) {
  Node *node = new Node(n);
  root = insertNode(root, node);    //*********** this line here
  insertFix(node);
}

Node* Tree::insertNode(Node* root, Node* node) {
  if (root == nullptr)
    return node;

  if(node->data < root->data) {
    root->left = insertNode(root->left, node);
    root->left->parent = root;
  } else if (node->data > root->data) {
    root->right = insertNode(root->right, node);
    root->right->parent = root;
  }
  return root;
}
```

Comment: `root` is first passed as an argument to the function. The , when the function returns, the result is assigned to `root`. There's nothing inherently wrong about that; they don't interfere.

Comment: For the program to know what is should assign to the left-hand side, the right-hand side must be fully evaluated first. It just doesn't make any sense doing it the opposite way.

Comment: I should have known that.. at least I did at some point.  Thanks to both of you.

Comment: Not a question you asked, but your use of enum's is a little off.  In Node, this line " int colour;" should be "colour colour;" instead, though using a variable name the same as the enum name probably isn't best.

Comment: While it is technically correct, and in some way even elegant in just assigning the left/right pointers this way, it is also a bit awkward because you will re-assign the same pointers over and over again once the tree has some elements and you need to iterate down to the next free position. And, btw, `insertNode` should be `private` I think.

Comment: Thanks Rene. I will change that to private. I'm still trying to get a grasp on when to use private / public